# Changing CRS in GeoPandas?

Tags: coordinate-system, geopandas

I'm trying to plot a bunch of points on a map of Britain and Ireland, and I've been using GeoPandas for that.

I've basically just been following the tutorials to do that, and slicing a world map with a Mercator projection such that it only shows Great Britain and Ireland. But somehow the aspect ratio (projection) ends up distorted.

Here's what my squashed map looks like now:

[image: My squashed map]

Here's what I've tried:

- Setting the `figsize` attribute to something with a larger height
- Assigning a different CRS
- Using a different plotting engine altogether (I can't seem to get Altair to work)

[My plot as it stands, with the geopandas code used to generate it, is here on GitHub](https://github.com/open-editions/corpus-joyce-portrait-TEI/blob/c522143dfd56fa9606b378004cd2cff705f7e884/analysis/analyze-geolocactions.ipynb).

What am I doing wrong, and how do I unsquash this map?

Comment: You can convert to another CRS with `to_crs`. When using a local CRS for the UK, you should get a better result.

Comment: Ah, I see. I had to do that *after* slicing it. It looks good now: https://github.com/open-editions/corpus-joyce-portrait-TEI/blob/master/analysis/analyze-geolocactions.ipynb

Comment: @joris please convert your comment into an answer so this thread can be marked as answered

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason it looks squashed like that is because GeoPandas naively plots the longitude and latitude with an equal aspect ratio.

To have a more realistic result, you can convert your data to a local CRS for the UK, using the `to_crs` method.

Comment: For an appropriate projection, please check related article [Appropriate map projection for the UK?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/74651/appropriate-map-projection-for-the-uk)